# writeablebitmap always render image with black background

Tags: windows-phone-8, writeablebitmap

I have next code:

```
var bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
  bmp.Render(new Canvas(){Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)}, null);
  bmp.Invalidate();
return bmp;
```

How I get colors:

```
var backColor = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundColor"].ToString();
var foreColor = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"].ToString();
```

I need to render image with white background. But this code always render image with black back. Foreground is ok, I've tested with next structure:

```
Canvas
   Textblock - with black foreground
   Textblock - with black foreground
```

So where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size of the canvas, otherwise it has a default Width and Height of 0, resulting in a transparent WriteableBitmap.

```
bmp.Render(new Canvas() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White), Width=(int)size.Height, Height=(int)size.Height }, null);
```

Comment: If so, my code would not work always.
But it works on dark phone theme and don't work on light.


    var backColor = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundColor"].ToString();
var foreColor = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"].ToString();

it's a how I get colors.

Comment: That's another problem. You should change the Background color of the Canvas based on the current user theme (light or dark).

Comment: Looks like you don't understand me.

When phone theme is dark - app will render image with black background and white foreground.
When  phone theme is light - app will render blank image with black background. Code not changed, but results is different

Comment: The phone theme can't change the WriteableBitmap background color automatically. I think that the rendered image background is transparent, that's why you when placed in a page you think it's based on the phone theme. Place it in a grid with a red background and tell me what color it is.

Comment: I create bitmaps with text for live tiles.
When I create new tile, I always use new WriteableBitmap instance with current phone settings. 
I can even set phone theme to light, deploy app and result will be same. 

 looks like it's a writeablebitmap issue or phone os issue.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know it was for creating a live tile. Did you try to set the background canvas color to (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]

Comment: I've tested again and found that background simple doesn't work.
In black theme it's look like background is black and tile look pretty. 
So I need to set background and all should works